# Как программно удалить повторы из текстовика?

Tags: delphi

Как программно удалить повторы из текстовика, в котором есть много строк с проксями (около 18000)?

Answer (score 1):

можно задействовать TDictionary, он должен быть пошустрее TStringList.

Answer (score 0):

Либо grep с Regexp(либо скрипты с ним), что гибче, либо notepad++ и его макросы (хотя нет в твоем случае не подойдет), что проще и у него в поиске то же есть regexp. А покажи пример то, что есть и что должно быть  и думаю маньяки regexp-a имеющиеся на форуме быстро подскажут решение.

Comment: ну например в текстовике: 
152.03.138.05:3127
131.247.2.242:3124
131.247.2.242:3124
190.144.139.227:80
203.160.1.85:80
212.100.132.146:3128
189.19.60.123:6588
82.134.53.6:80

и нужно удалить обе 131.247.2.242:3124
131.247.2.242:3124 и оставить только одну

Comment: http://www.rusdocs.com/text-duplicate-killer-utilita-dlya-udaleniya-iz-spiska-povtoryayushhixsya-strok

Comment: Если есть под рукой shell, то конвейер  sort proxies.txt | uniq -u должен решить проблему

Comment: А если разделители-пробелы, то замени их в том же нотепаде на переносы строк. Что-то я сегодня вообще никакой, даже не прочитал что нужно решение на дельфях. Фтопку меня.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так

```
   buffer: TStringList;
   n: Integer;
 begin
   list.Sort;
   buffer := TStringList.Create;
   try
     buffer.Sorted := True;
     buffer.Duplicates := dupIgnore;
     buffer.BeginUpdate;
     for n := 0 to list.Count - 1 do
       buffer.Add(list[n]) ;
     buffer.EndUpdate;
     list.Assign(buffer) ;
   finally
     FreeandNil(buffer) ;
   end;
 end;
```